# SQL query, BETWEEN. Windows forms. Запрос

Tags: c#, sql, база-данных, winforms, datepicker

Не работает SQL запрос с BETWEEN. Необходимо создавать отчет с данными о пациентах за период времени, заданный пользователем. Диапазон дат задается с помощью 2-х DateTimePicker. Ошибка именно в запросе. Подскажите где косяк?!До этого создавал отчеты с запросами за конкретный год или месяц - все работает на ура, а с этим совсем ничего не выходит.

---

```
if (radioButton3.Checked)
{
    DateTime d = Convert.ToDateTime(dateTimePicker3.Text);
    diap1 = Convert.ToInt32(d.Day);
    Mes = Convert.ToInt32(d.Month);
    God = Convert.ToInt32(d.Year);
    DateTime f = Convert.ToDateTime(dateTimePicker4.Text);
    diap2 = Convert.ToInt32(f.Day);
    Mes = Convert.ToInt32(f.Month);
    God = Convert.ToInt32(f.Year);
    MSEvsego = 0;
    sql = "Select count (*)  From First_Journal Where Date_Eks BETWEEN Day(Date_Eks)=@StartDay and Day(Dete_Eks)=@EndDay";
    connection = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.ConnectionString);
    command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection);
    command.Parameters.Add("@StartDay", SqlDbType.Int);
    command.Parameters["@StartDay"].Value = diap1;
    command.Parameters.Add("@EndDay", SqlDbType.Int);
    command.Parameters["@EndDay"].Value = diap2;
    command.Parameters.Add("@month", SqlDbType.Int);
    command.Parameters["@month"].Value = Mes;
    command.Parameters.Add("@year", SqlDbType.Int);
    command.Parameters["@year"].Value = God;
    try
    {
        connection.Open();
        MSEvsego += Convert.ToInt32(command.ExecuteScalar());
        connection.Close();
    }
    catch
    {
    }
```

Comment: "Не работает" - а что делает? "Ошибка именно в запросе" - как Вы это выяснили?

Comment: не работает, потому что в запросе написана какая-то ересь. Уберите все эти преобразования, вкидывайте две даты и их используйте в Between.

Comment: `Date_Eks BETWEEN Day(Date_Eks)=@StartDay and Day(Dete_Eks)=@EndDay` а как это должно работать? У between разве такой синтаксис?

Comment: @АндрейNOP не, не должно

Comment: @Igor Ошибка именно в запросе. Проверял все тысячу раз, если убрать Between и EndDay / StartDay (оставить что-то одно), работает прекрасно. Создана форма отчета при помощи CristalReport , данные в ней изменяются пока нет BETWEEN. Ереси в запросе нет никакой, все преобразования необходимы, т.к. если их убрать и оставить только дни, будет выдавать сумму выбранных дней по порядковому номеру за весь возможный календарь. Например если выбрать первые три числа месяца, получится сумма всех первых чисел,что возможны в календаре.

Comment: @АндрейNOP у BETWEEN вроде такой синтаксис. Я же оставил запись для получения замечаний и советов.

Comment: @Евгений26рус, дополните вопрос информацией об используемой БД и текстом сообщения об ошибке

Comment: @Андрей NOP текста сообщения об ошибки нет совсем. Если запрос неверный - результат не выносится в отчет и все. А БД состоит из 3-х журналов пациентов об инвалидности, направленных на экспертизу. Куча данных в каждом журнале, в отчет выносятся некоторые из них : какой журнал , мужчина / женщина, кол-во и тд. В статью кинул, только 1/12 часть вычисляемых данных, но там все по аналогии

Answer (score 1):

Оператор [BETWEEN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms187922(v=sql.120).aspx) имеет следующий синтаксис:

```
test_expression [ NOT ] BETWEEN begin_expression AND end_expression
```

Обратите внимание, `Аргумент test_expression должен быть того же типа данных, что и аргументы begin_expression и end_expression.`

Вы же пишете:

```
Date_Eks BETWEEN Day(Date_Eks)=@StartDay and Day(Dete_Eks)=@EndDay
```

У вас получается Date_Eks - типа Date, а выражения `Day(Date_Eks)=@StartDay` и `Day(Dete_Eks)=@EndDay` типа Boolean. Это, естественно, не работает.

Подозреваю, что вам нужно что-то вроде:

```
Date_Eks BETWEEN @StartDay and @EndDay
```

но тип @StartDay и @EndDay должен быть тоже Date

или:

```
Day(Date_Eks) BETWEEN @StartDay and @EndDay
```

но это вообще выглядит плохо

Comment: Спасибо за совет, я думал о типах данных, но идею эту не развил. Я обязательно попробую, дельное замечание! Теперь почти уверен , что в этом и проблема

Comment: @Евгений26рус, вы не написали какую БД используете. MSSQL? MySQL? Oracle? Другой вариант из тысячи?